# Binding to a sibling's child element

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, siblings

I'm working on a UserControl (named DiagramControl) and have a problem. The UserControl's code is as follows:

```
<UserControl>
   <Border>
      <Grid>
         <ScrollViewer x:Name="DesignerScrollViewer" ... />               
         ...
         <s:ZoomBox x:Name="zoomBox"
                   ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=DesignerScrollViewer}"/>
      </Grid>
   </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I am binding the ZoomBox (which has a scrollviewer DP) to DesignerScrollViewer. The method I use now works fine since the ZoomBox and DesignerScrollViewer are in the same XAML file.

What I would like to do however is to remove the ZoomBox from the control and define it in the window that uses the control. so for example something like:

```
<Grid>
   <s:DiagramControl x:Name="DC" ... />
   ...
   <s:ZoomBox ScrollViewer={Binding ElementName=DC,Path=DesignerScrollViewer}/>
</Grid>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. How can I perform the binding that I need?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out what I needed to do. I added a ScrollViewer DP to DiagramControl and had it update when the DesignerScrollViewer's Layout was updated. so the following went into my DiagramControl code behind:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ScrollViewer", typeof(ScrollViewer), typeof(DiagramControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ScrollViewer_PropertyChanged));

        public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
        {
            get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void ScrollViewer_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {                
        }

        private void DesignerScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer = DesignerScrollViewer;
    }
```

Now that the ScrollViewer DP had an update source i was able to bind to it from the window using the DiagramControl. Hope this helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't put UI controls into view-model properties (w/o a good reason - make a view-model hold all the info and bind to that instead) - your structure (view <-> view-model) gets too 'involved' and leads to more and more hacks - that out of the way :) ...

If I'm getting this right, what you're after...

Your `DesignerScrollViewer` is merely a 'child control', binding markup extension isn't aware of it.

> If you'd want something like that make a
>   `DesignerScrollViewerProperty` on the `UserControl` and put that into
>   the path (keep the `ElementName` part). That can be just a property
>   (you'd need `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raising event).

Or a bit differently, something like...

In your window somewhere:

```
<my:ZoomBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=diagramControl, Path=.}"></my:ZoomBox>
<my:DiagramControl x:Name="diagramControl"></my:DiagramControl>
```

Your ZoomBox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApp.ZoomBox" ...="">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="GoUp" Command="{Binding UpCommand}" Content="Go Up" IsDefault="False" />
        <Button x:Name="GoDown" Command="{Binding DownCommand}" Content="Go Down" IsDefault="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Your DiagramControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApp.DiagramControl" ...="">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="_scrollViewer" >
            ...
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...and Diagram code behind...

```
public partial class DiagramControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    RelayCommand _upCommand;
    RelayCommand _downCommand;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { this.PropertyChanged.Raise(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }

    public DiagramControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public RelayCommand UpCommand 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _upCommand ?? (_upCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param =>
                {
                    _scrollViewer.LineUp();
                },
                param => true)); 
        } 
    }

    public RelayCommand DownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _downCommand ?? (_downCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param =>
                {
                    _scrollViewer.LineDown();
                },
                param => true));
        }
    }
}
```

...you can bind to your DP instead (of `DataContext`). And put whatever actions (e.g. zoom in/out) you want instead of up/down.

This still isn't proper, to make it all right - you should bind your diagram and zoom box to the same view model (skip binding to user-controls directly - but 'communicate' via view-model, indirectly) - but that complicates a bit as you're going to need some events to handle Commands, and to make binding `TwoWay` for values to circulate back and forth etc.

Comment: Thanks @NSGaga that was the method i had tried first, as i had done in setting up the ScrollViewer DP for the ZoomBox. I didnt know what to bind it to tho. I have since figured it out, plz see my update thanks :)

Comment: which update :) - I don't think you understood it (or I'm missing it), I addressed what you're asking - it's another property you need - take a look again, dis mental the whole picture - and let me know if any questions

Comment: sorry bro just added the updates. My biggest problem was figuring out how to Bind the ScrollViewer DP to the DesignerScrollViewer, but then I realised I just had to set it on DesignerScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated

Comment: something like that - just you need only one DP (in ZoomBox), or the one property which is the 'target' of the binding - the other one just needs INotifyPropertyChanged - just so you understand things - glad it worked out.

Comment: Also, you can do away w/o DP if you use `DataContext` like I did (and that's the reason) - if you `ZoomBox` is only for that ScrollViewer. On the other side, if you want to `zoom` many controls at the same time - then you'd be better off with a 'agnostic view model' which both user-controls bind to - if you ever need that, you know where to look for (you cannot do that with entangling controls)